# Add identifier to squarespace sections

Tags: squarespace

Using the Squarespace 'Add Section' button and selecting a section style. Is there a way to label sections so that they can be specifically targeted using customer code? For example. Lets say I want to grab all the sections that have to do with "Products" and then "Sales" and style them differently with custom CSS? Note: some sections styles do not have "labels" on them for example lists.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Squarespace removed the ability to have custom section IDs in version 7.1 (that's the latest, at time of writing). That may have been useful in your case, but what it sounds like you want is the ability to assign a custom class to particular sections, and that's not a feature that Squarespace has ever provided.

The typical workaround for this is to target sections by their `data-section-id` attribute, like this:

```
section[data-section-id="5f870b03756b454a0f310e88"] {
  /* Your CSS Here */
}
```

If you have multiple sections which you want to target, it often looks something like:

```
section[data-section-id="5f870b03756b454a0f310e88"],
section[data-section-id="5f32be4fe69e956b3c47c805"],
section[data-section-id="5f870b2e692993607c0b1ba2"] {
  /* Your CSS Here */
}
```

Squarespace supports LESS CSS, which can be used in cases like this. For example, you could assign all of your Sales section styles to a class. And then, when customizing a section that is for Sales, you could apply that class along with other custom styles that perhaps do not apply to your other Sales sections. Something like this:

```
.salesSectionStyles {
   // Your Sales section-related CSS Here
   ul {
     // custom list styles here.
   }
}

section[data-section-id="5f870b03756b454a0f310e88"] {
  .salesSectionStyles;
  // More custom CSS here.
}

section[data-section-id="5f32be4fe69e956b3c47c805"] {
  .salesSectionStyles;
  // Even more custom CSS here.
}
```

Or, using LESS, you could maintain a variable such as `@salesSections` (to which you assign a string containing a selector of all sales-related sections) and then apply CSS to that variable. I wouldn't recommend this approach in most cases, but it would look something like this:

```
@salesSections: ~'section[data-section-id="5f870b03756b454a0f310e88"], section[data-section-id="5f32be4fe69e956b3c47c805"], section[data-section-id="5f870b2e692993607c0b1ba2"]';
                
@{salesSections} {
  // Your CSS Here
}
```

Keep in mind that the last two code snippets above use LESS CSS, something that Squarespace supports within the CSS Editor only (not within Code Blocks). It is not standard CSS. The first of the last two examples also illustrates the use of nesting with LESS in order to apply custom styles to all unordered list elements (`ul`) that are within a Sales-related section.